# Cast from int to custom struct C#

Tags: .net, generics, struct, casting, iconvertible

I am writing a custom generic VectorN class, where T: struct, IFormattable, IComparable, IConvertible.
I can access an indexed value of vector by this[int index]. So in a loop I do this piece of code to make VectorN.One:

```
r[i] = (T)Convert.ChangeType(1, typeof(T));
```

It works perfectly with standard numbers such as int, decimal, etc., however when I wrote a custom struct uHalfByte for testing, it gives an error:

> Invalid cast from 'System.Int32' to 'uHalfByte'.

Here is the script of uHalfByte:

```
struct uHalfByte : IFormattable, IComparable<uHalfByte>, IConvertible
{
    private byte val;
    public byte Val
    {
        get { return (byte)(val & 0xF); }
        set { val = (byte)(value & 0xF); }
    }
    public uHalfByte(byte val)
    {
        this.val = (byte)(val & 0xF);
    }

    public string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        if (formatProvider == null) formatProvider = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(format)) format = "G";
        string s = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) s += ((Val >> i) & 1).ToString(format,formatProvider);
        return s;
    }

    public int CompareTo(uHalfByte other)
    {
        return this.Val - other.Val;
    }

    public TypeCode GetTypeCode()
    {
        return TypeCode.Byte;
    }

    public bool ToBoolean(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return val!=0;
    }

    public char ToChar(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return (char)val;
    }

    public sbyte ToSByte(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return (sbyte)val;
    }

    public byte ToByte(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return (byte)val;
    }

    public short ToInt16(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return (short)val;
    }

    public ushort ToUInt16(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return (ushort)val;
    }

    public int ToInt32(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return (int)val;
    }

    public uint ToUInt32(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return (uint)val;
    }

    public long ToInt64(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return (long)val;
    }

    public ulong ToUInt64(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return (ulong)val;
    }

    public float ToSingle(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return (float)val;
    }

    public double ToDouble(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return (double)val;
    }

    public decimal ToDecimal(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return (decimal)val;
    }

    public DateTime ToDateTime(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return new DateTime(val);
    }

    public string ToString(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return ToString("", provider);
    }

    public object ToType(Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return Convert.ChangeType(val, conversionType);
    }

    public static explicit operator uHalfByte(int val)
    {
        return new uHalfByte((byte)val);
    }
}
```

Did I do something wrong in uHalfByte or it is just impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work in that way, because **System.Int32** (as stated in exception message) have no information about your custom class **uHalfByte** and can't perform that conversion. 
Of course it will work it other way **uHalfByte -> int**

Edit:
In your case I think you can use conversion operators:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/using-conversion-operators

like this:

```
struct uHalfByte
{
    public static explicit operator uHalfByte(int value)
    {
        return new uHalfByte();
    }
    public static explicit operator uHalfByte(string value)
    {
        return new uHalfByte();
    }
}
```

usage:

```
if (typeof(T) == typeof(uHalfByte)) 
    r[i] = (uHalfByte)value;
else
    r[i] = (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
```

Comment: However there is no option to implement a constructor in a struct interface and no option to use an abstract class as base of struct. How should IMyConvertibleExample look like?

Answer (score 0):

The solution based on @Thowk 's answer:
Implemented a generic interface:

```
public interface INumber<T>
{
    T ConvertGeneric<T1>(T1 item);
}
```

Added an implementation of the interface in my script:

```
    public struct uHalfByte : IFormattable, IComparable<uHalfByte>, IConvertible, INumber<uHalfByte>
    {
        ...
        public uHalfByte ConvertGeneric<T>(T item)
        {
            if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
            {
                return new uHalfByte((byte)(int)Convert.ChangeType(item, typeof(int)));
            }
            else if (typeof(T) == typeof(uint))
            {
                return new uHalfByte((byte)(uint)Convert.ChangeType(item, typeof(uint)));
            }
            else if (typeof(T) == typeof(long))
            {
                return new uHalfByte((byte)(long)Convert.ChangeType(item, typeof(long)));
            }
            else if (typeof(T) == typeof(ulong))
            {
                return new uHalfByte((byte)(ulong)Convert.ChangeType(item, typeof(ulong)));
            }
            else if (typeof(T) == typeof(short))
            {
                return new uHalfByte((byte)(short)Convert.ChangeType(item, typeof(short)));
            }
            else if (typeof(T) == typeof(ushort))
            {
                return new uHalfByte((byte)(ushort)Convert.ChangeType(item, typeof(ushort)));
            }
            else if (typeof(T) == typeof(byte))
            {
                return new uHalfByte((byte)Convert.ChangeType(item, typeof(byte)));
            }
            else if (typeof(T) == typeof(sbyte))
            {
                return new uHalfByte((byte)(sbyte)Convert.ChangeType(item, typeof(sbyte)));
            }
            else throw new NotSupportedException(string.Format("Type {0} is not supported, you have to write your own function!", typeof(T)));
        }
    }
```